# Insert value into non-identity key field : DB First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, identity, ef-database-first

Ran into a small problem while working on **EF 6 Database first approach**.

When I try to insert a value into the key field of a table which is not set to be the Identity, I receive the following exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'emp_main_id',column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I added the following code in the entity class to avoid the error

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int emp_main_id { get; set; }
```

but still could not get it working.

Below is the script to create the db table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesMain] (
    [emp_main_id]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_first]       NVARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_middle]      NVARCHAR (40)  NULL,
    [emp_main_last]        NVARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_dob]         DATE           NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_gender]      INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_type]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_email]       NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_password]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_designation] NVARCHAR (150) NULL,
    [emp_main_skill]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [emp_main_contract]    INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [emp_main_lead]        NVARCHAR (81)  NULL,
    [emp_main_img]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [emp_main_doj]         DATE           DEFAULT ('01-JAN-2012') NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [emp_main_primary_key] PRIMARY KEY ([emp_main_id])
);
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: did you  configure SQL to auto-generate (and auto-increment) the primary key ("emp_main_id") for the table upon inserts.

Comment: Check what Nazmul said... also, share the code where you are trying to add the object n object structure

Comment: Try adding [DataMember] attribute of emp_main_id field

Comment: @Nazmul: Yes, initially the field was an identity field and was set to auto-increment. I removed the property and made it a simple key field without auto-generation of the value.

Comment: @Akanksha: tried adding [DataMember] to the field. Still getting the same error.

Comment: is it worked before you removed the property ?

Comment: @Nazmul - Did not try inserting a value explicitly when the field was an identity. The values were getting generated by themselves, so there was no need for that.

Comment: "Update Model from Database". try again

Comment: @Nazmul: did that already

Comment: share  your  table script code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111391/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-iamruku).

Comment: you did not set auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to write the answer myself.

The problem was, since I had set the field as an identity earlier, the values for the field were being generated automatically. Even after removing the identity and updating the model from the database, this was not reset.

So what I had to do was,

> 1. Go to the .edmx file.
> 2. Right click on the property "emp_main_id"
> 3. Click on **Properties**
> 4. Set **StoreGeneratedPatter** to **None**
> 5. Save the model and rebuild the solution

That's it. it gives me a non-identity key, with all the other constraints along with the option to explicitly enter a value for the field. Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem is you are trying to insert NULL value to a Primary Key
   column i.e emp_main_id.
2. Primary Key doesn't allow to insert NULL values or duplicate values.
3. If you want to insert NULL values remove Primary Key constraint.